# how to pass data from array to database using jackcess

Tags: java, arrays, ms-access, gridview, jackcess

Hi basically im doing this to retrieve data from database to array

```
 for(i=0;i<numfilas;i++){
    HashMap<Object, Object> rowdata = new HashMap<Object, Object>(cur.getNextRow());
    for(j=0;j<numcolumnas;j++){
        datos[posicion]=rowdata.get(nombrecolumnas[j]).toString();
        posicion++;
    }
    }
```

then I pass the data to EditTexts so the user can edit it and after that I update the array, the problem is how do I take this data and send it back to the database?

Am I getting in trouble with datatypes? because the array is String type and the database had int Type, String Type, long type .....

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

> Am I getting in trouble with datatypes? because the array is String type and the database had int Type, String Type, long type .....

You could be, if any of the fields you are trying to update are `Date/Time` fields in Access. Jackcess is able to implicitly cast strings to numbers (in many cases, anyway), but it is not able to do that when it comes to dates.

For the sample data in a table named [Members]

```
MemberID  MemberName  SponsorID  DateJoined  FeePaid
--------  ----------  ---------  ----------  -------
       1  Gord                   2014-01-16        0
```

the following code works fine

```java
try (Database db = DatabaseBuilder.open(new File("C:/Users/Public/mdbTest.mdb"))) { 
    Table table = db.getTable("Members");
    Row row = CursorBuilder.findRow(table, Collections.singletonMap("MemberID", 1));
    if (row != null) {
        row.put("SponsorID", "0");  // "Long Integer" in Access
        row.put("FeePaid", "130");  // "Currency" in Access
        table.updateRow(row);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("row not found.");
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(System.out);
}
```

However, this will not work

```java
row.put("DateJoined", "2014-01-23");  // "Date/Time" in Access
```

because Jackcess cannot implicitly cast the string value to its internal (numeric) date value, Instead you need to do something like this

```java
org.joda.time.DateTime dt = new org.joda.time.DateTime("2014-01-23");
row.put("DateJoined", dt.getMillis());
```

As an alternative, you may want to investigate [UCanAccess](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ucanaccess/). It is a pure-Java JDBC driver that uses Jackcess to perform reads and writes on the Access database but lets you do it using more "normal" SQL methods like this:

```java
Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection(
        "jdbc:ucanaccess://C:/Users/Public/mdbTest.mdb");
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(
        "UPDATE Members SET " +
            "SponsorID=?, " +
            "DateJoined=?, " +
            "FeePaid=? " +
        "WHERE MemberID=1");
ps.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt("0"));
org.joda.time.DateTime dt = new org.joda.time.DateTime("2014-01-23");
ps.setTimestamp(2, new Timestamp(dt.getMillis()));
ps.setBigDecimal(3, new BigDecimal("130"));
ps.executeUpdate();
```